# Hard Modulo arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

If I have $$c ≡ 169 \mod1643\\c=m^7\mod1643\\m=c^{951}\mod1643$$

How would I go about solving for m

I tried to write $$m^7 ≡169\mod1643$$

but I'm not sure what do do from here

Comment: $1643=31\times 53$...do everything for the smaller values separately and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that as in what to rewrite the equations to to make it easier

Comment: The CRT lets you build solutions $\pmod {pq}$ out of solutions $\pmod p$ and $\pmod q$.  Makes the computation easier.  Mind you, personally I'd just solve the original by a quick computer search but if you want to do it by hand I'd do it the way I sketched.

Comment: Thank you that helped it think I got 1073 if thats correct?

Comment: Presumably you got $1073$ from $169^7 \pmod {1643}$ but that is the wrong direction.

Comment: For what?  The solution to $m^7\equiv 169 \pmod {1643}$ is $524$ (by computer search).  On the other hand, $169^{951}\equiv 1372 \pmod {1643}$  Not sure what relation you wanted or expected there.

Comment: To be clear:  my comments and proposed method were intended to address the problem $m^7\equiv 169\pmod {1643}$.  I don't understand what connection this has to the other congruence you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is $m\equiv 169^{951} \pmod {1643}$.  Feeding that to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=169%5E7%20mod%201643) gives $1372$.  Then $1372^7 \equiv 1335 \pmod {1643}$ so your equivalences are inconsistent.

Comment: Im sorry I actually made a mistake in my workings with the 3rd equation it should be $m=c^{223} mod 1643$. So would I need to calculate $m≡169^{223}$mod 1643?

Comment: as 524 from wolfram but is there a  way to calculate it manually.

Comment: You are right that $524$ works.  I don't know an easy way to calculate it.